# How can I check if a MATLAB handle is valid?

Tags: matlab, graphics, handle

I manipulate data on a plot using its handle:

```
x = 1:10; y = sin(x);
h1 = line(x,y);
```

However, if the figure gets closed before the script actually terminates, doing something like this returns an error.

```
>>set(h1,'Color','green') % line is green
??? Error using ==> set
Invalid handle object.
```

Is there a way to check if `h1` is a valid handle before doing any manipulations with it?

Comment: An alternative to checking a handle, which may be useful for some cases, is to `set(h1, 'DeleteFcn', @delete_fcn_callback)`, where `function delete_fcn_callback(hObj, event)` is something you define and it will be called when the figure is being deleted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`ishandle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ishandle.html) function to check first if a graphics handle is valid:

```
if ishandle(h1)
  set(h1, 'Color', 'green');
end
```

**UPDATE:**

For newer versions of MATLAB, handle objects are actual objects, not just numeric values. The better option is to use the [`isvalid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.isvalid.html) method for handle objects:

```
if isvalid(h1)
  set(h1, 'Color', 'green');
end
```

Comment: If you know what type of object you're looking for, you can test for it explicitly. Replace
if ishandle(h1)
with e.g.
if ishandle(h1) && strcmp(get(h1,'type'),'line')

Comment: a=0. ishandle(a) returns true. But a is not a figure, so: incomplete answer.

Comment: @Pedro77: Incorrect. If you are storing handles, as in the example, and checking them later with `ishandle` to make sure they are still valid, then you will never get a situation where the handle is 0. Only the root object can be zero; graphics handles will never be.

Comment: What I'm using is: " if isgraphics(figHandle,'figure') && ishandle(figHandle)  "

Comment: @Pedro77: If you need to check that a handle is a specific type of graphics object handle *and* is valid, `isgraphics` is all you need (it checks validity already). If you only need to check validity, and don't care what specific type of graphics object it is (or already know), `isvalid` is all you need.

Answer (score 4):

Note that ishandle has a drawback in that it also accepts common numeric values like 0 (=desktop handle) and 1 (=the first open figure by default) which are often also valid handles although possibly not the *expected* handle. You will then still see an error if you try to set a non-existent property.

To handle such cases, simply place your code within an exception-handling block:

```
try
   set(myHandle,propName,propValue);
catch
   % do something useful... (recreate the GUI?)
end
```

Comment: A try/catch block is a good solution. However, the handle `0` is always reserved for the root object and plot objects or uicontrols always have floating-point handles. Figures have integer handles by default, but you can force MATLAB to use a floating-point handle for figures by creating the figure with the property 'IntegerHandle` set to 'off'. This will avoid the situation where a figure is created, the integer handle is stored, and then the figure is deleted and a new figure created with the same integer handle (so it's actually a different figure than the first handle refers to).